# How to see if a remotely controlled Mac is powered off completely

Tags: sleep-wake, power, remote-desktop, shutdown

I have an 13 inch MacBook Pro which I run with closed lid all the time over a VNC connection.

To power it on, I power up the mains adapter and the energy settings on the Mac are configured so that this will turn on the Mac.

To power it off, I choose shutdown over the VNC connection.
Sometimes, not often, the Mac will hang during shutdown and not power off completely.

Is there a way / some kind of gadget, maybe via USB / or any other method to see if the Mac is powered off safely? The Mac is in same room, so a LED or something would be in view.

Thanks,

Comment: Most new macs don’t have an LED, unless you’re talking about the keyboard backlight. However, I think you should solve the hanging on shutdown issue as you shouldn’t need a gadget to properly power off a Mac

Comment: Does `sudo halt`work better?

Comment: I'd quit all apps before shutdown. You could even do a terminal ps aux and quit the processes you do not need.

Comment: Hmm, I can't solve the shutdown problem. It can't be reproduced that easy. And I have no idea how I can debug the issue. Also I close all apps before shutdown. I was hoping for some clever idea / some gadget which could show the active or power-off state e.g. via USB port.. Thanks